# Unprotected endpoint in an express app that use passport-local as auth strategy

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, middleware

I'm wondering how to create an endpoint (GET, POST, etc...) that can be accessed without any authentication. this is my code:

```
router.use(AuthenticationManager.ensureAuthenticated());

router.use('/', require('./index'));
router.use('/path-1', require('./path1'));
router.use('/path-2', require('./path2'));
```

All the endpoints will enjoy the `Authentication Manager`. How disable that authentication manager only in some endpoints inside `./path1` or `./path2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular method of doing this is defining those endpoints before the `AuthenticationManager` middleware:

```
router.use('/path-1/unprotected', require('./path1'));
router.use('/path-2/unprotected', require('./path2'));
router.use(AuthenticationManager.ensureAuthenticated());
```

It depends on what exactly `path1.js` and `path2.js` are exporting if it works as-is, or if you need to do a bit of rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use authentication for specific endpoint by using this:

```
app.post('/profile', AuthenticationManager.ensureAuthenticated , userController.getUserProfile);
```